# Check if the trigger was fired by INSERT or DELETE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, trigger, insert

I know this is the easiest question you can find on this website but I wasn't able to find its answer on the internet.

How to check if the trigger was fired by an `INSERT` or `DELETE`?

#### Example

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TestTrigger]
On [dbo].[Table1]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE
AS
    --if save
    --do some work

    --else if delete
    --do some work other work
```

I want to do some work if it's an **insert** and some other work if it is a **delete**.

Please provide a code snippet for the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as the trigger is only for insert/delete:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
   -- I am an insert
ELSE
   -- I am a delete
```

And in fact if you are doing things based on a join to inserted/deleted, it can be even simpler:

```
-- do something for an insert
-- this will only actually do anything when it's an insert
INSERT dbo.somewhereElse SELECT whatever, 'insert'
  FROM dbo.sourceTable AS s
  INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON s.id = i.id;

-- do something for a delete
-- this will only actually do anything when it's a delete
INSERT dbo.somewhereElse SELECT whatever, 'delete'
  FROM dbo.sourceTable AS s
  INNER JOIN deleted AS d ON s.id = d.id;
```

If you add the update action to the trigger, the logic gets more complex, of course:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
  BEGIN
    -- I am an update
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    -- I am an insert
  END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- I am a delete
END
```

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Since my comment went unanswered, I have converted it to an answer.</sub>

> I want to do some work if it's an **insert** and some other work if it is a **delete**.

You could create separate triggers, one for insert, and one for delete:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Table1_AI
ON dbo.Table1
AFTER INSERT
AS
... insert-specific actions
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Table1_AD
ON dbo.Table1
AFTER DELETE
AS
... delete-specific actions
```